# Pyinstaller & Pyzbar - Could not find module

Tags: python, pyinstaller

everyone.
I try to convert my python script .py to .exe… but its not work as well…

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBsop.jpg)

I use auto-py-to-exe (onefile and onedir), —hidden-import pyzbar and installed visual c++ 2013 x64 and x86. Both with the same error: could not find module.

Some ideas to solve that?

Installed visual c++ x64 and x86, use —hidden -import pyzbar and try -onefile and -onedir

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.